# How do I set my activity to portrait mode but still allow the user to rotate the device 180 degrees?

Tags: android, android-activity

How do I setup my activity, in code, to support either SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT or SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT?

I want to enforce portrait mode, but I don't care which side is up and which side is down.

It would be nice if something like the following works (but it doesn't):

```
setRequestedOrientation( ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT | ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT );
```

Maybe a separate question, is there any way to accomplish this without using SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT since I'm targeting android 2.1 (api level 7) and that wasn't introduced until api level 9.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no, there is no way to do it before api 9

long answer is yes but it would require you to handle the accelerometer listeners and screen canvas yourself rather than relying on the system to do it.

If you cannot / don't want to build for API 9 I suggest that you just stick with SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT for now. Handling the rotations yourself would likely be somewhat of a pain, and is likely to introduce some very odd display bugs

In my opinion supporting reverse orientation makes way more sense if you are in landscape rather than portrait. It seems to me that a user would be far more likely to have their device in either right side down, or left side down for landscape mode then that they would have their device all the way upside down for portrait.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tim.  I'm afraid I need to target api 7.  My fear is that users running on a device like the Xoom, which doesn't really have an up or a down, will be frustrated that the app can't figure out how to flip for them automatically.